# Displaying items in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I need to add items to the QTableWidget,The Items are QList qList, I tried some code as

```
int row = 0;
QList<Players>::iterator j;
                for (j = qList.begin(); j != qList.end(); ++j){
                    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(qList.count);
                    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(j->playerName) );
                    ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(j->playerRank) );
                    row++;

        }
```

where playerName and playerRank are some properties in Players class.

```
class Players
{
public:
    Players();
    int playerId;
    QString playerName;
    int playerRank;
};
```

But nothing displays in the QTableWidget. How To do this?

Comment: Just an advice, do not have public variables. Use `get`ers and `set`ers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment if there is some issue with something else without seeing the entire code but this line seems wrong

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(qList.count);
```

From [qtablewidget documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#insertRow)

> void QTableWidget::insertRow(int row)
> Inserts an empty row into the table at *row*.

`qlist.count` appears to be the total length of list. You are inserting a row at position `qlist.count` and not adding `qlist.count` rows. Even this logic seems wrong as you are adding n^2 rows for n elements (*adding inside for loop*). You should look at [`setRowCount`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#setRowCount)

Make this line like this

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(row);
```

Comment: Yes changing to row worked, But the output does not display the playerRank in QTableWidget

Comment: @SyedIftekharuddin Did you set column count ?

Comment: Yes, ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2); in MainWindow constructor

Comment: What does [`ui->tableWidget->columnCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#columnCount) return just before the for loop ?

Comment: ui->tableWidget->columnCount(), It returns 2

Comment: It seems that cannot insert int value directly

Comment: @SyedIftekharuddin Alright. I suggest you convert integer to string. You could use [`tr`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/i18n-source-translation.html#using-tr-to-obtain-a-translation). This is an altogether different question, but this is how you translate an integer to string `tr("%n", "", n)`. Or you could use [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/sstream) to convert integer to string.